# Is it possible to have an Array of hstore in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, postgresql-9.1

I am a complete beginner in PostgreSQL. And I was really amazed by the hstore datatype provided by Postgres. Well, I am using the Rails 3 framework and developing a simple app that uses PostgreSQL. I want to store an array of hashes in a field.
For Eg.:

```
authors: [
           {
             name: "abc",
             email: "abc@example.com"
           },
           {
             name: "xyz",
             email: "xyz@example.com"
           }
         ]
```

Is this possible in PostgreSQL using Rails 3? If so, can somebody give insights on how?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it certainly is possible on PG side: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/16e4c/3

Comment: Do you know how do you implement this in Rails. I am a complete newbie to rails. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's certainly possible to create an array-of-hstore column in Rails 4 with e.g. a column spec like this in the table creation:

```
t.hstore :properties, :array => true
```

However, there's an encoding bug in Rails 4.0 that unfortunately renders them unusable; essentially you can read from them and they present correctly as arrays of hashes, but not write.

I've opened an issue (with fix patch) at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11135 which hopefully will be incorporated soon.

Comment: Thank you!
Looking forward for the rails team to incorporate it.

Comment: Thanks for working on this @inopinatus! Do you have any ideas on how to pass the hstore array as a string so that it gets into the database correctly until your patch becomes a part of Rails?

Comment: Your answer seems to conflict with the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306434/can-i-store-arrays-in-hstore-with-rails are you certain this can be done?

Comment: @noz given that my patch to do it is now in production rails, yes I'm sure!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if they'll allow you to have an hstore array, but there are a few active record extensions that add hstore and array types. e.g.:

https://github.com/funny-falcon/activerecord-postgresql-arrays

https://github.com/engageis/activerecord-postgres-hstore

https://github.com/tlconnor/activerecord-postgres-array

Don't miss the Rails 4-related improvements, too:

http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/a-love-affair-with-postgresql-rails-4-countdown-to-2013