# Can I store arrays in hstore with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore

I want to save data like this:

`User.create(name:"Guy", properties:{url:["url1","url2","url3"], street_address:"asdf"})`

Can I do so in Rails 4? So far, I have tried migration:
`add_column :users, :properties, :hstore, array: true`

But when I save the array in hstore, it returns error:

`PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information`

Comment: You can: https://github.com/tombenner/nested-hstore

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`hstore` is intended for simple key/value storage, where both the keys and values are simple unstructured strings. From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html):

> **F.16. hstore**
>
> This module implements the `store` data type for storing sets of key/value pairs within a single PostgreSQL value. [...] Keys and values are simply text strings.

Note the last sentence: keys and values in `hstore` are strings. That means that you can't put an array in an `hstore` value without some handholding to convert the array to and from a string and you really don't want to be messing around with that sort of thing.

However, there is a [JSON data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html) available:

> **8.14. JSON Type**
>
> The `json` data type can be used to store JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) data, as specified in RFC 4627.

and JSON can easily handle embedded arrays and objects. Try using JSON instead:

```
add_column :users, :properties, :json
```

You'll have to remove the old `hstore` column first though.

Also, you didn't want `array: true` on your `hstore` column as you weren't storing an array of `hstore`s, you just wanted one of them.

Comment: Very well explained, thank you. Is there any downside to use JSON instead of hstore? such as performance issues?

Comment: I don't think you'll have any performance issues when storing simple properties. The JSON will be validated by the database but that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You should know that at the moment hstore provides flexibility over querying your data as well indexes.

Comment: Note: The hstore extension has a cast from hstore to json, so that converted hstore values are represented as JSON objects, not as string values. Excerpt from PostgresDocs

Comment: @SaadMasood 9.4 should clean up a lot of the hstore vs json stuff (as noted by [Ivan Wang below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22315531/479863)) when hstore and jsonb pretty much become equivalent, no?

Comment: Any idea how to validate array using hstore?

Comment: @phlegx: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I mean, how to validate the array parameter in Rails with a validator before save it in hstore.

Comment: @phlegx Maybe you should ask a new question so that you have enough room to provide enough detail for someone to know what you mean.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in the meantime I have found the solution. See here: https://gist.github.com/phlegx/73c3a74701aa047dd913

Comment: Thanks mu. Here's nice explanation how to use it with RoR. http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 10):

Add on Mu's answer. Hstore is also giving very promising update in a few month (Postgresql 9.4 will launch in 3rd quarter of 2014).

Some [highlights](http://sarahbranon.com/post/70117417009/improved-hstore-the-h-is-for-hooray) of the coming changes which should address these limitations:

- Support for scalars and types (numeric, boolean, strings, NULL)
  support, along with new corresponding operators
- Support for nesting and arrays (the authors propose that output
  format, i.e. brackets v. curly braces, be configured with GUC
  variables)
- Essentially, full compatibility between hstore and JSON, so JSON
  documents can now take full advantage of hstore’s indexes (with GIN
  in particular, the authors ballparked a 120x speed improvement for
  JSON search performance)

It is very hard to pick one between hstore and json right now. Because they are just getting way too similar and updating too quickly.

Comment: The link is not working. Wondering whether one can store full arrays as values under text keys nowadays. I could cast a `{1, 3, 4}` text value to an array manually, but it seems it is still stored as simple text.

Answer (score 8):

*My 2 cents to Mu's answer. I'm posting this as an answer cause I don't have enough reputation to add a comment.*

JSON is becoming the go-to solution for storing "complex" data.

Oleg Bartunov--one of the authors of hstore--himself stated that there is no advantage using hstore over JSON and he [encourages people use jsonb](http://obartunov.livejournal.com/175235.html?thread=523395#t523395).

On Mar 23, 2014 [jsonb, a structured format for storing json](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1WRpmB-0002et-MT@gemulon.postgresql.org), was formally introduced in the pgsql development mailing list.

On May 15, 2014 JSONB was listed in the [PostgreSQL 9.4 Beta 1](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1522/) release announcement.

> JSONB: 9.4 includes the new JSONB "binary JSON" type. This new storage format for document data is higher-performance, and comes with indexing, functions and operators for manipulating JSON data.